# Build phonegap app run using cli

Tags: cordova, phonegap-build, phonegap-cli

I have phonegap app which build using build.phonegap.com

I have cordova installed on my machine

I want to create build using `cordova build ios` But it says `Current working directory is not a Cordova-based project`, Because project structure for local project and project of build.phonegap.com is diffrent

So how can i build it locally?

Comment: Create a barebone cordova project. Copy the code from phonegap project to the new project, install necessary plugins and build it

Comment: what about plugin which set in config.xml as `<gap:plugin ...`

Comment: All of those can be installed using cordova plugin add command in CLI

Comment: so i have to install all those plugin manually using cli?

Comment: Yes as far as i know.But its not tedious

Comment: Else try mentioning plugin name in config.xml as in this link https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/config_ref/index.html#sample-configxml and see if it works. Have never tried this personally though